# jQuery deferred: Nesting promises in methods, last callback too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, deferred

I have a problem with deferreds/promises. I have a main function that calls two functions that have to be executed serially. The first one contains a bunch of asynchronous web service calls that have to be executed serially first. But actually my second function is called before every asynchronous feedback in the first function is there.

I built a small example that shows my problem: https://fiddle.jshell.net/qLf1c0uq/

Here is the code for reference:

```js
function first() {
  $('ul').append("<li>first started</li>");
  let deferred = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() { // Any async function.
    $('ul').append("<li>first ended</li>");
    deferred.resolve();
  }, 2000);
  return deferred.promise();
}

function second(da) {
  $('ul').append("<li>second started</li>");
  let deferred = $.Deferred();
  $('ul').append("<li>second ended</li>");
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise();
}

function third(da) {
  $('ul').append('<li>third started</li>')
  let deferred = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('ul').append("<li>third ended</li>");
    deferred.resolve();
  }, 2000);

  return deferred.promise();
}

function GroupFunction1() {
  let deferred = $.Deferred();
  $('ul').append("<li>Group 1 started</li>");
  var data = "test2";
  $.when(first()).then(function() {
    second(data);
  }).then(function() {
    third("test2");
  }).then(function() {
    $('ul').append("<li>Group 1 ended</li>");
    deferred.resolve();
  });

  return deferred.promise();
}

function GroupFunction2() {
  $('ul').append("<li>Group 2 started</li>");

  $('ul').append("<li>Group 2 ended</li>");
}

$(function() {
  $.when(GroupFunction1()).then(GroupFunction2);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

The GroupFunction2 is started before the third function ends. I was expecting it vice versa.

Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `return` the promises inside your callback functions. That's the only way the promise chain can wait on them.

Also, you're abusing the Explicit Promise Creation Antipattern.

`.then()` returns a promise. You can just return that. And there's no point in passing a single promise into `$.when()` because all `$.when()` is going to do is spit it right back out:

```js
function first() {
  $('ul').append("<li>first started</li>");
  let deferred = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() { // Any async function.
    $('ul').append("<li>first ended</li>");
    deferred.resolve();
  }, 2000);
  return deferred.promise();
}

function second(da) {
  $('ul').append("<li>second started</li>");
  let deferred = $.Deferred();
  $('ul').append("<li>second ended</li>");
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise();
}

function third(da) {
  $('ul').append('<li>third started</li>')
  let deferred = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('ul').append("<li>third ended</li>");
    deferred.resolve();
  }, 2000);

  return deferred.promise();
}

function GroupFunction1() {
  let deferred = $.Deferred();
  $('ul').append("<li>Group 1 started</li>");
  var data = "test2";

  // v-- here
  return first()      // v-- here
    .then(function() { return second(data); })
    .then(function() { return third("test2"); })
    .then(function() { $('ul').append("<li>Group 1 ended</li>"); });
}

function GroupFunction2() {
  $('ul').append("<li>Group 2 started</li>");

  $('ul').append("<li>Group 2 ended</li>");
}

$(function() {
  GroupFunction1().then(GroupFunction2);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: OK, I understood your comments on then(), but I didn't get your first paragraph: How would I return the promise in the callback functions of setTimeout? It doesn't make sense to me, to move the "return deferred.promise()" to the end of an asynchronous call?! Sorry ...

Comment: @UweGrohne You don't need to return them in the callbacks in `setTimeout`. You need to return them in the callbacks in `.then()`. See the changes I made to your `GroupFunction1` function. The code in my answer has all the modifications I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question; JLRishe already explained why your code didn't wait for your promises.

This is rather a cleanup, and I've included a little utility that wraps setTimeout into a Promise so you don't have to do it maunally and don't repeat yourself all over the place.

```js
function first(data) {
  $('ul').append("<li>first started</li>");
  return wait(2000)
    .then(function(){
      $('ul').append("<li>first ended</li>");
    });
}

function second(data) {
  $('ul').append("<li>second started</li>");
  $('ul').append("<li>second ended</li>");
  //let's stay consistent with our API
  //even if we have to return an empty/pointless Promise for that
  return Promise.resolve();
}

function third(data) {
  $('ul').append("<li>third started</li>");
  return wait(2000)
    .then(function(){
      $('ul').append("<li>third ended</li>");
    });
}


function GroupFunction1() {
  $('ul').append("<li>Group 1 started</li>");
  var data = "test2";
  return first(data)
    //.then(wait(1000))  //maybe a little pause in between?
    .then(function(){
      return second(data);
    })
    //.then(wait(1000))  //maybe a little pause in between?
    .then(function(){
      return third(data);
    })
    .then(function() {
      $('ul').append("<li>Group 1 ended</li>");
    });
}

function GroupFunction2() {
  $('ul').append("<li>Group 2 started</li>");

  $('ul').append("<li>Group 2 ended</li>");
  return Promise.resolve(); //again, just staying consistent
}

//DRY. Get rid of all the manual setTiemouts and the Deferreds and wrap them into a function:

//Examples on how to use:
//promise = somePromise.then(wait(1000)).then(someFn);
//promise = wait(1000).then(someFn);
//promise = wait(1000).resolve(42);
//promise = wait(30000).reject("timeout");
const wait = (function(){
 const reject = Promise.reject.bind(Promise);
 const methods = {
  then(a,b){ return this().then(a,b) },
  resolve(value){ return this(value) },
  reject(err){ return this(err).then(reject) }
 };
 return delay => Object.assign(value => new Promise(resolve => void setTimeout(resolve, delay, value)), methods);
})();

$(function() {
  GroupFunction1().then(GroupFunction2);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```